# Custom hierarchy

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've a table source

```
idGeo     GEO   PARENTID
1   EMEA    NULL
2   France  1
3   mIDCAPSfRANCE   2
4   Germany 1
5   France exl midcaps  2
6   Amercias    NULL
7   US  6
```

The expected result of the hierarchy

[image]

I tried to do left join(self join) but I'm not able to get exactly as expected.

Comment: please do not post image. Use formatted text instead. Also show your attempt and explain the logic required to obtain the required result

Comment: For the future, you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) how to edit tables, should it be necessary. Also, for [tag:sql] questions it is more useful to post input data as SQL dump (a list of `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements). For justification, please see the discussion at [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Finally, saying what you tried to do is great, but it would be awesome if code would accompany it.

Comment: Is levels count limited by 3?

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev, there's no restriction on the number of levels

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev, for the moment it can be fixed for three levels

Comment: For tree levels you can use something like https://sqlize.online/sql/mssql2017/7f34918507bae9d9b74af96c5f5e83dc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a generic method regardless of the level of the hierarchy.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl table (
    idGeo INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    GEO   VARCHAR(64),
    PARENTID INT
);

insert into @tbl (GEO, PARENTID) values 
(   'EMEA',    NULL),
(   'France',  1),
(   'mIDCAPSfRANCE',   2),
(   'Germany', 1),
(   'France exl midcaps',  2),
(   'Amercias',    NULL),
(   'US',  6);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

--SELECT * FROM @tbl;

WITH cte AS 
(
    -- Anchor query
    SELECT idGEO, GEO, ParentID, 1 AS [Level]
        , CAST('/' + GEO AS VARCHAR(1000)) AS XPath
    FROM @tbl
    WHERE ParentID IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    -- Recursive query
    SELECT t.idGEO, t.GEO, t.ParentID, cte.[Level] + 1 AS [Level]
        , CAST(cte.[XPath] + '/' +  t.GEO AS VARCHAR(1000)) AS [XPath]
    FROM @tbl AS t
        INNER JOIN cte ON t.ParentID = cte.idGEO
    WHERE t.ParentID IS NOT NULL 
)
SELECT idGEO
    , REPLICATE('  ',[Level]-1) + GEO AS GEOHierarchy
    , GEO, ParentID, [Level], [XPath]
FROM cte
ORDER BY XPath;
```

**Output**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand you want to generate columns as the levels go on.
You cannot dynalically generate columns, SQL is a fixed column language.

Comment: This is not quite true: you can build a query dynamically in a variable, and `EXECUTE sp_executesql` it. But it does complicate matters considerably.

Comment: This is generaly a bad idea

Comment: Yes. But there is a difference between "bad idea" and "can't do it".